# Why is class of T not allowed in a generic type?

Tags: delphi

Consider this program:

```
type
  TMyClass<T: class> = class
  public type
    TClassOfT = class of T;
  end;

begin
end.
```

This fails to compile at the declaration of `TClassOfT` with the error message:

```
E2021 Class type required
```

Can anyone explain why this is so? If I were to instantiate this class with, for instance `TMyClass<TObject>` then surely `class of TObject` would be meaningful. I constrained the generic parameter to be a class. So how can the compiler object that `T` is not a class type?

Comment: Looks like an oversight in the compiler.

Comment: @UweRaabe What makes me a little hesitant to submit a QC report is the fact that I get a proper compiler error rather than an ICE.

Comment: I would still submit a QC report. The worst they can do is close it with "as designed".

Comment: Uwe's right.  There are a lot of things in the Generics system where the implications of constraints you have placed haven't been completely thought through.  This looks like one of them.

Comment: @MartynA That's an obvious syntax error in my view. In any case you'd surely write it `TClassOf<T: class> = class of T` but that will never work. You have to define a class or a record.

Comment: Ah, now at least I know I wasn't just floundering about when I tried to use something like that to get my DIY DI working with meta classes and specific constructors. Not that it would have worked, DI wouldn't have known what parameters to pass, and that's why I didn't follow through, but still...

Comment: OT: you are getting closer and closer to owing me that drink ... :-D

Comment: Yep. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Oooh nice! How did you know? It's about the only type of beer I like :-) (Most "ordinary" lagers just give my headaches)

Comment: Well, what if you declare TMyClass<Integer>? there would be class of Integer?

Comment: @Matheus That instantiation would not satisfy the constraint on T, T: class.

Comment: I didn't see that constraint before, interesting

Comment: @Matheus The question hinges on the constraint. Without it I have no grounds to expect class of T to compile.

Comment: They forgotten to update `class of` when they created Generics, haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I can tell, there is no reason for the compiler to reject this code. Thus, I believe that it is a design flaw and have submitted [QC#121178](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121178).